# how to achieve consistent positioning on a tooltip for an element that changes position

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, css-animations

I have a tooltip on an element transitions to the right when the container is hovered over.

The issue is that about 50% of the time during this animation the cursor will end up hovering over the toggle before the animation is complete. This results in an incorrectly positioned tooltip.

[gif of behavior](https://gyazo.com/188c7749571cf6dc81324dd45739d277)

Any thoughts on how to avoid such behavior would be greatly appreciated.